# How do you continue a line in solid style in dotted style?

Tags: pine-script

I draw a line in solid style on the highest and also on the lowest candle. When the next candle breaks the line from above or below then the line is interompu. But how do I get the line to continue as a dotted line after the break?

```
if showLine
    dt = time - time[1]
    line.new(x1=time - dt * max, y1=high[max], x2=time, y2=high[max], color=lineColor, 
style=line.style_solid, width=2, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    line.new(x1=time - dt * max, y1=low[max], x2=time, y2=low[max], color=lineColor, 
style=line.style_solid, width=2, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot partially change the style of a line. You actually need two lines.

The first one would go until there is a break. Then you create a new line with the dotted style from that point onwards.

Comment: Ok I see, do you have an example of how to do this?